# Communication between java socket and android using Serializable objects

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, serializable

My situation right now is quite wired, I have for one side Android app running a service with a network thread.

On the other side a java application runing on my laptop (win8). The java app is listening in a serversocket, waiting for the android app comunicate with it. Once the android app create a socket and bind it to the correct port and address the Server socket in the java app accept it and create a new socket.

This new socket is waiting packets from the Android app (client). The android app sends a serializable object.

The problem is that the java app never read it, but I sniff with wireshark and the packet is being received.

So I try to read a byte array, and works good, the socket read it without problems.

Any guess with this is happening? My code I think is good, it's a pretty basic stuff, and I did it few times between android apps, don't know why is not working now.

**Server (java app)**

```
mServerSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

        mReceivedSocket = new Socket();

        mReceivedSocket = mServerSocket.accept();

        System.out.println("Accepted");

        mInput = new ObjectInputStream(mReceivedSocket.getInputStream());

        mOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(mReceivedSocket.getOutputStream());

        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];

        while (mReceivedSocket.isConnected()) {

            System.out.println("Waiting for packets");

            mInput.read(buf, 0, 4096);

            //NotificationPacket packet = (NotificationPacket) mInput.readObject();

            System.out.println("Packet received: "+buf.toString());

            //renderPacket(packet);

        }
```

**Client send (Android app)**

```
mOutput.writeObject(packet);

        mOutput.flush();
```

The Serializable packet is the same in both sides.

Thanks.

Comment: what happens when readObject() is called? does it sits indefinitely?

Comment: yes, I use the debugger and it stays there... don't know why, looks like is waiting for read more

Comment: You can't use isConnected() as a connection health check. It isn't. Catch exceptions. That's what they're for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to construct the ObjectOutputStream before the ObjectInputStream, at both ends, otherwise you can get a deadlock. You also have to *read objects,* at both ends. You are writing an object but reading into a byte array. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes I was reading objects in both side, this code is after trying to see if it's ready something I didn't notice... I will try what you say about the order...

Comment: I try it yesterday and the order is important... hehe thank you. I didn't know that was important.